# RegEx to check if a string starts and end with a particular character

Tags: java, regex, actionscript-3

I need a regular expression that checks if the string starts and end with a special character like -

```
%ASDF%

"ASDF"

@ASDF@
```

Comment: did you try anything by yourself? Even if you casually search for regex here or in Google, you'll get umpteen results for that.

Comment: Try it here please http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following regex matches strings that begin and end with the same character:

```
(.).*\1
```

`.` stands for any character and enclosing is for marking a capture group so that it can be backreferenced.

`.*` matches zero or more characters.

`\1` backreferences the first capture group (i.e. the first character)

So it matches **aba**, **#ee#**, **ee** etc. If you require at least one character between starting and ending characters, replace the `*` with `+`.

Answer (score 4):

```
^((%.+%)|(".+")|(@.+@))$
```

- `^` means start of the line
- `$` means end of the line
- `|` means or
- `.` means any character
- `+` means repeated 1 or more times